# Load facenet model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, facenet

I have tried almost all the answers on stackoverflow but nothing worked. Here is my code.

```
from keras.models import load_model
load_model('facenet_keras.h5')
```

It is giving me this error

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_5776\2622147163.py in 
> ----> 1 load_model('facenet_keras.h5')
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py
> in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
> 68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
> 69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
> ---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
> 71         finally:
> 72             del filtered_tb
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py
> in func_load(code, defaults, closure, globs)
> 101     except (UnicodeEncodeError, binascii.Error):
> 102         raw_code = code.encode("raw_unicode_escape")
> --> 103     code = marshal.loads(raw_code)
> 104     if globs is None:
> 105         globs = globals()
>
> ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)

To solve the above error I did this

```
from keras_facenet import FaceNet
embedder = FaceNet()
```

But I don't want to use the above method.I want to load the facenet model only.How to solve this error if anyone can help.

1. Python verison : 3.9.3
2. tensorflow : 2.11.0
3. keras : 2.11.0

**EDIT**

According to V.M's answer, this worked.

```
model = InceptionResNetV1(
        input_shape=(None, None, 3),
        classes=512,
    )
model.load_weights('20180402-114759.h5')
```

Comment: Do you have the facenet_keras model saved locally? load_model() works by loading a model from a filepath.

Comment: @stephen_mugisha I have model saved locally.

Comment: @V.M, if you have read my question propelry then I had already did that thing but I don't want to use it.

Comment: It looks to be an issue with the python version. https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/16669
Try using a lower version of python and see

Comment: I dont want to lower the version of python nor either of keras or tensorflow. I want to load the model in my current configurations only

Answer (score 0):

If you can recreate the architecture, in this case from `[keras_facenet/inception_resnet_v1][1]`, then you can do:

```
model = InceptionResNetV1(
        input_shape=(None, None, 3),
        classes=512,
    )
model.load_weights('model.h5')
```

Comment: from where I will get model.h5

Comment: I tried to load above metioned model in load_model(''), but getting the same error

Comment: You need to recreate the architecture as mentioned above. The architecture can be obtained from - https://github.com/nyoki-mtl/keras-facenet/blob/master/code/inception_resnet_v1.py

Comment: let me try that

Comment: this worked. You can see my edited question. Now what is the next step.

Comment: I have to load facenet_keras.h5 model.

Answer (score 0):

Use this insted:

```
model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(weights='imagenet')
```

This works for me. In our code, you will not be able to use the 'predict' attribute for embeddings, but using this you can.

before implementing you just need to install one dependency using the bellow code in your terminal:

```
#pip install keras_facenet
```